# Hot questions are not that hot currently

Tags: bug, hot-questions

I just added the [Hot This Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/month/hot) tab to my browser and the questions in there seem not that hot.

The list is the same for [Hot Today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/today/hot) and [Hot This Week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/week/hot).

That must be a bug, right?

Comment: The other issue is all of those links return the 404 page from the mobile view

Comment: They are bad links on desktop view as well.  Use the tabs, like http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month.  Looks sizzling enough.

Comment: @hans: But when I choose "Where are my tabs" and select to see the old ones, then I get exactly the links I mention in my post. BTW your link does not work for me. It just opens the Main page in default view

Comment: I noticed this a while ago, but I just thought it was due to the fact that there aren't enough up votes on new quality content. Or something.

Comment: Maybe it just needs curation and style. "Skeet's Hot Takes", or maybe just "Hot Skeets"?

Comment: The irony is that this post is now a hot meta post.

Comment: Two weeks later, all three links still show the same [-6 - 0] votes questions..

Comment: Now it is almost 3 weeks and still not a single response from the team for that obvious bug. Sigh... [Nothing has changed in the last years](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186803/why-dont-we-get-responses-from-bug-reports).

Comment: Was about to ask a new question on this but found yours. All three of my "Hot this month/week/today" show the same result and aren't particularly hot either. How has this not been addressed?